# How to used trained model to test data and plot graph?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I know this question is asked more than one time, but I couldn't understand codes or the logic behind.

In my data set, first I created a layer, sigmoid layer, then I connected this layer to the output layer and I've used softmax function in the output layer.

```
fl = tf.layers.dense(x, 10,activation=tf.sigmoid)
output = tf.layers.dense(fl, 2,activation=tf.nn.softmax)
```

I've created loss and accuracy, initialized variables, set optimizer and train variables, then I start running on my data:

```
loss = tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(onehot_labels=y,logits=output)
accuracy = tf.metrics.accuracy(tf.argmax(y_train,1),tf.argmax(output,1))

# inits
init_local = tf.local_variables_initializer()
init_global = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init_global)
sess.run(init_local)
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(rate)
train = optimizer.minimize(loss)

for i in range(1000):
    _, lv = sess.run((train, loss))
    if i%5 == 0:
        print("L: " + str(lv))
print("Accuracy: "+str(sess.run(accuracy)))
```

I can see that my loss value decreases every time I run on the training set. And my accuracy is ~0.93.

The problem is, from now on, I don't know how to test this model with real data.

Also, how can I draw a histogram of my real data? I have correct labels for my real data as well.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that you use Dataset to feed your training data and you want to run on test data immediately after training (since you don't have checkpoints in your code).

When using Dataset, you would create an iterator and call `get_next()` on it. Then, you would use the return values of `get_next()` as inputs to your model.

To run your model on the test data, you can use two high-level approaches:

- If you test data has the same format as you train data, create a dataset that reads your test data. Then, create another copy (sometimes called a "tower") of your model (operations will be new but variables will be shared) that uses the test Dataset. Then, use `sess.run()` similarly to how you use it for training - you might not need to compute loss or train, but only accuracy.
- If you test data has different format, you can feed it directly, by using `feed_dict` argument to `sess.run()`. You would feed your test data as values for tensors returned from `get_next()`. Usually, one feeds placeholders, but TensorFlow allows you to feed any tensor.

As for histograms, Tensorboard has a nice way of visualizing them: https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/tensorboard_histograms.